# how to pass parameter 'WebElement' to method and make action 'wait' on him

Tags: typescript, webdriver, protractor

I would like to do something like this in TypeScript:

```
public wait(element){
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element), 5000);
}
```

but I get the message "[ts] Property 'element' does not exist on type 'BasePage'"
How to do this better?

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually want this to be an `ElementFinder` and not a `WebElement`. The [documentation](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.visibilityOf) says that `visibilityOf()` accepts an `ElementFinder` object. From the variable name, it looks like you are trying to pass in the entire page object. You need to pass in a specific element from that page object.

So in your case you would just get an element the usual way and pass it to this function.

```
var myElement = element(by.css('.some-class'));
myUtils.wait(myElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is:
Make an import in spec file:

```
import {browser, by, $, $$, ExpectedConditions as EC, element} from 'protractor';
```

then in **'it'** block where you want to wait for an element write this:

```
const waitforMyDesiredElement = EC.visibilityOf(element);
browser.wait(waitforMyDesiredElement, 5000)
```